# Laravel Eloquent update multiple rows with same value but different ID

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm using Laravel 6 and Eloquent. I'm looking for a way to update a set of rows with a set value, each identified with a unique ID.

This is what I'm doing right now:

```
$ids = [3948, 1984, 7849, 4456, 394];
$value = false;

foreach ($ids as $id)
{
   User::where("id", $id)->update(["status" => $value]);
}
```

Is there a way to accomplish the same with only 1 query instead of 5?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `whereIn`, like:

```
$ids = [3948, 1984, 7849, 4456, 394];
$value = false;
User::whereIn("id", $ids)->update(["status" => $value]);
```